# replace a word that contains a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to sanitize a logfile and replace all hostnames containing the word `lab` with `sanitized`

If I knew all the possible hostnames, I could loop the replace but there are many hundreds of hostnames yet all contain the word `lab` eg:

- steve-lab-food
- two-lab-four
- hello-lab-dog

I have tried the following:

```
(get-content .\log.txt) -replace '\*lab\*', "sanitized"
(get-content .\log.txt) -replace '*lab*', "sanitized"
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the logfile?  Maybe four or five lines (and especially the header line if this is a CSV).  Remember to manually sanitize it before sharing it.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Manu he did.  It's just not well-formatted.

Comment: Yes, I just formatted it. It was a big block of text.

Comment: @FoxDeploy There's already a sample.  It's now formatted properly.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'd like to see the log file itself, depending on formatting, it could be easy or...less easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses regex so your wildcard attempt will not work, but your method is correct.

```
## \w+ captures 1+ word characters
## -lab- captures case-insensitive literally
## .*? captures any characters up to a whitespace
## )+ captures 1+ instances
$Pattern = '(\w+-lab-.*?)+'
(Get-Content -Path 'Logfile.txt') -replace $Pattern,'sanitized_hostname' |
    Out-File -FilePath 'Sanitized_Logfile.txt' -Encoding 'UTF8'
    ## Set-Content -Path 'Logfile.txt' -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

Comment: That successfully replaces the word lab, but only lab. I need it to replace the full hostname steve-lab-food and the rest of the hostnames which all contain the word  lab

Comment: Are the hostnames all formatted in the `word-word-word` format @Steve?

Comment: 5/25/2017    9:49:21 AM    Scan Summary    NAVS-LAB-UEA02    Scan Summary
5/25/2017    9:49:21 AM    Scan Summary    NAV3-LAB-UE04    Files scanned : 0
5/25/2017    9:49:21 AM    Scan Summary    NAV5-LAB-UE06    Files with detections :  0
5/25/2017    9:49:21 AM    Scan Summary    WIN-LAB-UE08    File detections :  0
5/25/2017    9:49:21 AM    Scan Summary    NAVS-LAB-UEA02    Files cleaned : 0

Comment: I need to figure out the proper formatting but that is a small example of this text file log. The hostnames can be located in any column as the log data changes. This is why i am trying to match on the one common factor "LAB" and then replace everything including both sides with sanitized

Comment: @Steve Updated my post, give it a shot

Comment: Why is a capture needed?

Comment: @lit For cases of multiple captures on a single line in the logfile

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - Using `'\w*-lab-\w*'` works on multiple occurrences for me.

Comment: @lit In the same line?  I've had mixed results but I work with all versions of powershell (v2-5) in my environment so there may be implementation differences somewhere.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - I am running 5.0.10586.117.

Comment: In the case where steve-lab-food is the only stated hostname, both '\w*-lab-\w*' and '(\w+-lab-\w+)+' worked well. What would I need in the case where the domain is included such as steve-lab-food.corp.lab.com ? The output leaves the domain separated by periods ?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible, no sir, as I ran it against another log, I found that the full domain appended. How do I include the domain in the -replace as well ?

Comment: @Steve `'\w+-lab-\w+(\.\w+)*'`

Comment: no sir, using that, I have the entire hostname. i am on $psv 4.0

Comment: @Steve What is your goal output from a FQDN input?

Comment: My intent is to replace the entire name with "sanitized_hostname"

Comment: some of the logs are in the GIG's in size, there is no way I could manually edit these so I am trying powershell as it is installed on our workstations

Comment: @Steve More specifically, if you have `dog-lab-red.test.domain.com` you want literally `sanitized_hostname`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible yes sir, I have to replace the entire hostname

Comment: I've updated my example and in my testing, it is working @Steve

Comment: @TheIncorrigible I chose "sanitized_hostname" to indicate that is what was being replaced. I am replacing several other items but the hostname is what  really became difficult

Comment: @TheIncorrigible That worked !!! Although the replacement of sanitized_hostname did not appear. Do single quotes matter over double quotes?

Comment: @Steve All double quotes signify is a non-literal string (they support string expansion, subexpressions, etc.)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible   I replaced my ip addresses with sanitized_ip_address successfully but the hostnames are blank using the same syntax. But the important part is that the name has been deleted. Thank you !!!

Comment: @Steve I did one last update that should capture what you're targeting.  What it gets replaced with is specified by what's after the comma in your `-replace`.  If my answer answered your question, please accept it as the answer.